# php5.6-fpm curl stops working (Couldn't resolve host)

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm, php5, curl

All of a sudden our Ubuntu php5.6-fpm server has stopped working with curl requests.

Here is what i have found:

Works when ran from the console `php test.php`.

Works via wet from `console wget -qO- https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Brooklyn+NY+USA&key=AIzaSyBGgTVnShML1_WHJL0rOTEnt2XOrgVgnu4 | cat`

Works using curl from `console ums-admin@svr1:/var/www/propertymonitor.ae/htdocs/v2$ curl https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Brooklyn+NY+USA&key=AIzaSyBGgTVnShML1_WHJL0rOTEnt2XOrgVgnu4`

However calling the script via php-fpm on https://example.com/test.php it does not work and complains about DNS lookup failure?!

Restarting php5.6-fpm and it starts working again?!

Code below:

```
<?php
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Brooklyn+NY+USA&key=AIzaSyBGgTVnShML1_WHJL0rOTEnt2XOrgVgnu4");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if ($data === false)
{
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
echo 'Response: ' . $data;
}

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

And the rest of the system checks out:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search example.com
```

And no packet loss:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3150 ttl=46 time=129 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3151 ttl=46 time=124 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3152 ttl=46 time=124 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3153 ttl=46 time=124 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3153 packets transmitted, 3153 received, 0% packet loss, time 3154312ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 114.975/124.705/139.692/2.004 ms
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1674733

An update caused this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the bug is [fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1674532) and released.

[image: apt history log]

Comment: Would the fix be installed with `apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: If you have automatic security updates it should be updated already. Otherwise `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, at it seems to work. Looks like the packages got downgraded.

Comment: Which versions are where it is fixed? Seeing the below:

`wheel@svr1:~$ apt-cache show libc6-dev | grep Version
Version: 2.23-0ubuntu7
Version: 2.23-0ubuntu3`

Comment: Version 2.23-0ubuntu7